# Ajax associative array

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm confused about how associative indexing and javascript.

In my javascript, I do this:

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function () {
    var checked = {};
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checked[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    var value = [];
    value.push($(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());

    $.ajax({ url: "scripts/php/generatehtml.php",
        data: {action: value},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        success: ...<cut for brevity>});
```

So in my PHP code, I do this:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    var_dump($_POST['action']);
}
```

And get this:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
  string(5) "12277"
 }
```

As you can see, that's an indexed array, I want an associative array.
But whenver I do something like:

```
value['id'] = $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val()
```

Nothing gets sent.

I'm not very good wtih Ajax, and any help here would be really great!

NOTE: I did look at the other ajax array answers, but I don't think they answer my question.

Comment: JSON (javascript, generally) does not use "associative arrays", it uses Objects instead. The shorthand syntax for initializing a variable as an object is curly braces instead of "square" braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an associative array, initialize your variable as one. That way you can add values corresponding to specific properties like so:

```
var value = {};
value['id']=$(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();
```

Comment: (Note the substitution of curly brackets for your square brackets)

Comment: @adola that's just the syntax for a literal javascript object with no properties. Keep in mind that with JS' loose typing, both these types boil down to just being objects. However using `[]` declares an object which inherits from `Array`, which isn't what you want in this case.

Comment: Oh, ok. 

I suppose it's my extreme lack of Javascript, but I certainly do hate this language.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use associative index arrays in JS.

You can use a JS Object instead :

```
var value = {};
```

Then you can do :

```
value['id'] = $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val()
```

Or

```
value.id = $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment:

```
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        checked[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    }
```

can be replaced by:

```
    if (this.checked) {
      checked[this.name] = this.value;
    }
```